# How to view a secondary index in RethinkDB data explorer?

Tags: database, rethinkdb, graphql

So I cannot seem to figure out the syntax for RethinkDb's web UI data explorer. I have a "secondary index" within a table, within a db. It has approx 20k documents. I would like to just see the documents output to JSON, perhaps the 100 most recent documents.

Here's what I have so far, which doesn't seem to be working:

```
r.db('users').table('leads').orderBy('createdAt').limit(10).coerceTo('array').toJSON()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use something like [`getAll("", {index: "secondary_index"})`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/get_all/) that allows you to query with an index. And you might have to play around with the first arg to see what you can do to get all the entries where that field isn't null.